# Managing constants in different projects

Tags: c#, architecture, global-variables, constants

I have a C# Application consisting of a product core and different special cases for each customer project.
I need a way to handle and manage global constants (everything at a central point) and came up with the following solution:

In project "Core":

```
public abstract class Config
{
   //Core values, which are always needed
   public const string Value1 = "abc";
   ...
}
```

In the specific project "SpecialProject1" (which references Core):

```
public abstract class SpecialConfig : Config
{
   //additional extra values for this special case
   public const string Value2 = "xyz";
   ...
}
```

This way I can inherit from my Core Config class and avoid that somebody accidently creates an instance of my Config-classes (they have no state, just fixed values).

Is there a better way to do this? Is there a problem with using "abstract" in this cases?

Comment: Do you need to prevent people from accidentally creating an instance of your config class? What harm would they do if they did? Personally I'd always prefer to not have config settings in compiled code to avoid having to do a new build just to change a config setting. Having a class that loads an XML config file or from a database. Then you would only need an identifier for each customer to allow you to get the right config.

Comment: I would not do any big harm, but there is just no need to create an instance. Most of the config values are coming from xml files, but some things are just...well, constants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instread of an abstract class use a static class:

```
public static class Config
{
   //Core values, which are always needed
   public const string Value1 = "abc";
   ...
}
```

and refer to your variables as `Config.Value1` rather than inheriting from the class. Since C# only allows you to inherit from one base class it's not a great idea to force uses to inherit needlessly.

Also, a static class can never be instanciated, so you don't have to worry about people creating an instance of it.

In "SpecialProject1" have a config class that relates just to the config for that project, so that you keep core config and project config seperate.

Comment: I thaught of that first, but then I will need to write code like this: SpecialMethode(CoreConfig.Value1, SpecialConfig.Value2). I just want to have one "class" per project which contains everything.

Comment: @HectorLector - fair enough. It's just that in my experience it's good to split config into logical domains rather than lump it all together. This way the user has a clear understanding of what settings belong to a particular domain.

Comment: You have a point, I will consider it. Thanks for your help. Otherwise do you see any obvious problems with my "abstract"-approach?

Comment: @HectorLector - there's nothing wrong with your approach, but you can't really stop someone create an instance indirectly. For example, they can just derive from `Config` and make the derived class non-abstract.

Comment: Thanks, I didn´t thaught about that, but then somebody really has put much evil effort in it (any may has his reasons). I just want to cover the basic case if someone writes: Config conf = new Config(); because it seems like a good idea.